# Python Virtual Environment Activation Problem

Tags: python, environment-variables, virtual-environment

Hay,
I Have A Problem…After I Create A Virtual Environment In Python Using:

```
python -m venv env
```

Then When I Try To Activate It Using:

```
env\Scripts\activate.bat
```

Nothing Happens…Like This:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cjqwk.png)

Iam Beginner In Programming and I Have Started With Python

Python Version : 3.8.10

OS : Windows 7 64-bit

I Wish Someone Can Help.

Comment: Call `activate.bat` from a command prompt (instead of power shell) and it should work

Comment: Thanks It Worked..But I'm Still  Beginner..Can you tell me what is the different between Power shell and command prompt

Comment: Those are just two entirely different things. But you do not have to use the command prompt, you can stick with powershell if you want. In that case, you should run the powershell activate, `env\Scripts\Activate.ps1`.